# OpenXML oversize xml information

Tags: t-sql, datatable, sql-server-openxml

I am successfuly using OpenXML for some time now, but I encounter a problem when sometimes an xml string passed to sql is to large to fit the parameter.

How to solve this issue, instead of just limiting datatable length to fit the xml string.

Thanks

Comment: Used xml instead of varchar to pass data to t-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used xml instead of varchar to pass data to t-sql

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reading into a string? It's a zip file so ready it in binary mode direct into the OpenXML SDK. Or if you are not in .net, same thing but direct into whatever zip file library you are using.

Comment: I suggest you store/read it from Oracle as a BLOB. And that can be read in as a stream.